# How to invoke simultaneously two methods of my DomainService in WCF Ria services

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I’m working with silverlight 4.0 WCF Ria services and I want to invoke simultaneously two methods of my DomainService.

In my GUI i have two buttons:
The first one invokes method1 which takes many time to achieve treatment (there is an iteration in treatment and there is a counter variable).
The second one invokes method2 which return a counter value indicating progression of first treatment.

When I invoke method1 then method2
I can obtain the result of method2 only when method1 complete

But I want to follow progression of treatment whenever I clicked on button2

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I understood the question wrong. When you click button 1, I would call both Method1 and Method2 with same *'on complete event'* which will wait for both the method to complete. On the other hand, when button 2 clicked, you need to call only method 2, with **different** *on complete event*, with this, method 1 is never called and you will get your progression indicator directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. But my purpose is to execute method1 and method2 simultaneously. In other words the execution of the method1 which takes a long time should not block the execution of method 2 which is faster

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214621/multiple-calls-to-the-same-web-service-blocking by setting the max connection, you can submit multiple request same time.

Comment: thank you for your replay but this not resolve my problem. Method2 is alwayes executed after method1

Comment: sorry,thank you for your answer but doing this method2 is always executed after method1 not simultanious

Comment: Even after the change in the concurrent tasks, method2 is executed after method1? Can you run fiddler and see if both the requests make it to server on same time or is send one after another based on completion of the methods?

Comment: thanks for your disponibility. In fiddler, i see that the two requests are sent to the server at same time but the result of method2 is sent always after the result of method1 although method1 takes 1 minute and method2 takes 3 seconds

Comment: Ok I am able to duplicate the problem locally with a sample project and I am going to take a look at it and get back to you.