# Very strange WCF limitation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, wcf, concurrency

I have made a very simple WCF web service with only one method. That method takes 5 seconds to execute before it returns control to the caller.

I have also made a client application that starts up 10 identical threads, each one calling the web service method in a loop.

When I run both the service and the client on the same machine, all ten threads can make web service calls concurrently.

However, when I run the service and the client on *separate* machines, only *two* threads can make concurrent calls - 8 threads seems constantly to be forced to wait until it becomes "their turn"!

I can start as many instances of the client application as I want, but each client instance only shows max. two concurrent web service calls at a time (unless both client and service are on the same machine)

How can that be? Where is the limitation? And can anything be done about it?

Comment: I suspect this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214621/multiple-calls-to-the-same-web-service-blocking

Comment: Fantastic, you were spot on! The small config addition solved the problem. Thanks man!